# linking using href

Tags: jsp, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [linking jsp to servlet and that to servlet again shows some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018660/linking-jsp-to-servlet-and-that-to-servlet-again-shows-some-problems)

I tried to link a servlet to a jsp using href.
My code is,

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String emailid=request.getParameter("user");
out.println("<a href=\"mahi6.jsp?emailid=<%=emailid%>\">Send information to someone</a>");
```

In jsp,

```
<%
            String e1=(String)request.getParameter("emailid");
            if(e1!=null)
                               {
            %>
            <br>
            Enter the email id of the user you wanna send info to
            <input type="text" name="user1" value="" size="15"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="u1" value=<%=u1%> />
            <input type="hidden" name="e1" value=<%=e1%> />
            <input type="submit" value="proceed"/>
            <%
                              }
            %>
```

But when I run it, I get a blank page. That mens the emailid is null. I have checked in the servlet, the emailid is not null there.
What is the mistake?