# linking jsp to servlet and that to servlet again shows some problems

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have written a jsp code which links to a servlet and that links to a servlet again.
The code,
mahi1.jsp

```
<form action="mahi5" method="post">
<center>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1><center> SIGN IN </center></h1>
    </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Email:<nbsp>   <nbsp>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="user" value="" size="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>          
        <tr>
            <td>Password:<nbsp>  <nbsp></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="pass" value="" size="20" />
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
        </table>  

</center>
</form>
```

servlet-mahi5.java

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            String emailid=request.getParameter("user");
            String password=request.getParameter("pass");
            out.println("<a href=\"a2?m="+emailid+"\">");
            out.println("Send information to someone</a>");
}
```

jsp-mahi6.jsp

```
<%
            String e1=(String)request.getParameter("emailid");
            if(e1!=null)
                               {
            %>
            <br>
            Enter the email id of the user you wanna send info to
            <input type="text" name="user1" value="" size="15"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="u1" value=<%=u1%> />
            <input type="hidden" name="e1" value=<%=e1%> />
            <input type="submit" value="proceed"/>
            <%
                              }
            %>
```

When i click the submit button in the first jsp page, it displays a blank page.
The url says its mahi5
Could anyone help me please!

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in Servlet's service method.

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String emailid=request.getParameter("user");
out.println("<a href=\"mahi6.jsp?emailid=" + emailid + "\">Send information to someone</a>");
```

Comment: @Tim Post no!!! Its not the same. see, in this question, the error mentioned in the answer above is rectified. But still the output doesnot come!

Comment: @user1607653 That's fine, and the question shows the rectified code. There's no reason for this answer to not be merged. The question is still open, your initial error is clear, yet the problem remains on the same topic, in a question that now has much more information.

Comment: @Tim Post The difference is, in the previous question, I have said that I said the servlet code didnot work, in this post I have said, when the submit button of the jsp page is created, a blank page is displayed? clear? Now the error occurs at a different place. So please remove your duplicate reference!